# h:panelGrid with embedded h:graphicImage not displaying correctly

Tags: jsf

My question regards the display of h:graphicImage within a h:panelGrid

```
<h:panelGrid border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
   <h:graphicImage height="63" width="270" value="images/NewAOnly.PNG" />
    <h:graphicImage height="60" width="270"        value="images/NewABottom.PNG" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

The top .PNG file is 270 x 63 with no border area.  The bottom .PNG is 270 x 60 with no border area.

My question is, with border="0", cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0", why do the two images not sit one on top of the other with no space between them?

Answer (score 3):

This will happen when you use a [strict doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). Long story short, check the article on Mozilla Developer Network: [Images, Tables, and Mysterious Gaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps). As to the doctype, you can fix this by using a quirks or transitional doctype (as a quick test, remove the `DOCTYPE` line altogether). This is however not recommended these days.

If you're absolutely positive that the table is the right tool for your concrete functional requirement of displaying images this way and e.g. a div is for some dubious reason absolutely not an option (and you're fully aware of the importance of "[Semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)"), then you can fix this by making the images in table cells block level elements.

```
td img {
    display: block;
}
```

Please note that this problem is completely unrelated to JSF. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator.